# Selenium using Python. How find the right element?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

There is a date selection on the site I need.
I need the program to click on the current day.
Fortunately, he has a different class `class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight"`

The choice of dates is divided into 5 identical blocks, in which there are 7 more identical blocks with days.

I need to find the current one among all the days, When I start going through all the days to see if there is a line I need there, I get an error message.

My full code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('**site**')

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ait-schedlfind-datepickers']")
option = element.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ait-schedlfind-cal1 hasDatepicker']")
option.click()

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ait-schedl-picker']")
table = element.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']")
tr = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

for v in tr:
    td = v.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for k in td:
        currect_day = k.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ui-state-default ui-state-highlight']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a loop to select the element you need. Everything after `option.click()` can be replaced with:

```
correct_day = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'ui-state-highlight')]")
# You can check that it's the correct day with
# print(correct_day.text)
```